# simle textButton libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm new to libgdx. Trying to implement simple button but nothing appears on the screen.

```
 font = new BitmapFont();
        skinButton=new Skin();
        buttonAtlas = new TextureAtlas("button_back/button.txt");
        skinButton.addRegions(buttonAtlas);
        textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
        textButtonStyle.font = font;

        textButtonStyle.up = skinButton.getDrawable("rounded_rectangle_button");
        textButtonStyle.down = skinButton.getDrawable("rounded_rectangle_button");
        textButtonStyle.checked = skinButton.getDrawable("rounded_rectangle_button");
        button=new TextButton("Finish",textButtonStyle);
        button.setText("Finish");
        button.setHeight(230);
        button.setWidth(500);
        button.setPosition(50,50);
        stage.addActor(button);
```

button.txt

```
button.png
format: RGBA8888
filter: Linear,Linear
repeat: none
rounded_rectangle_button
  rotate: false
  xy: 2, 2
  size: 256, 108
  orig: 256, 128
  offset: 0, 10
  index: -1
```

I placed button.png file in the same folder as button.txt

Comment: If you aren't getting any uncaught exceptions, the problem is probably related to your camera or viewport setup. Can you post that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your code is fine. I copy+pasted it into a barebones app, and changed the name of the image in my button.txt file, but otherwise it worked. As Tenfour04 said, do you have your camera/viewport (or rendering code), etc setup correctly?

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;

public class SimpleTextButton implements ApplicationListener {
   private SpriteBatch batch;
   private OrthographicCamera camera;
   private Stage stage;
   private BitmapFont font;
   private Skin skinButton;
   private TextureAtlas buttonAtlas;
   private TextButton.TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle;
   private TextButton button;

   @Override
   public void create() {
      camera = new OrthographicCamera();
      camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
      batch = new SpriteBatch();
      stage = new Stage();

      font = new BitmapFont();
      skinButton=new Skin();
      buttonAtlas = new TextureAtlas("img/sprites/buttons/button.txt");
      skinButton.addRegions(buttonAtlas);
      textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
      textButtonStyle.font = font;

      textButtonStyle.up = skinButton.getDrawable("rounded_rectangle_button");
      textButtonStyle.down = skinButton.getDrawable("rounded_rectangle_button");
      textButtonStyle.checked = skinButton.getDrawable("rounded_rectangle_button");
      button=new TextButton("Finish",textButtonStyle);
      button.setText("Finish");
      button.setHeight(230);
      button.setWidth(500);
      button.setPosition(50,50);
      stage.addActor(button);         
   }

   @Override
   public void render() {
       stage.draw();
   }

   @Override
   public void dispose() {
       buttonAtlas.dispose();
       font.dispose();
       skinButton.dispose();
       buttonAtlas.dispose();
       batch.dispose();
   }

   @Override
   public void resize(int width, int height) {
   }

   @Override
   public void pause() {
   }

   @Override
   public void resume() {
   }
```

}